# TFS Upgrade 2012 to 2015

Tags: tfs

We are upgrading TFS from 2012 to 2015  and i wanted to confirm if the APP Tier machine configuration does affect the upgrade performance if the APP Tier has a high configuration LIKE : Big Memory size , Lot of empty disk space . Will this things improve the upgrade performance ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most performance during the upgrade can be had from optimizations to the SQL server.

1. Your SQL server's available memory and cores. More = better.
2. Your SQL server's tempdb optimization (multiple tempdb's help a lot)
3. Your SQL server's MaxDOP setting to something other than 0

If you're using a SQL server on a SAN drive, make sure that it's optimized for both read and writes, often these are optimized for reading, which can seriously slow down your upgrade.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2013/10/08/what-does-a-well-maintained-team-foundation-server-look-like.aspx

And on the Apptier there's a few things that may help:

1. at least 50GB free disk space
2. Available CPU's, some of the migration jobs process a lot of data